# upgrading data.table fread operation from 32-bit to 64-bit?

Tags: r, data.table, 64-bit, fread, 32-bit

I tried to open up a csv and it complained about this:

```
 Opened 0TB (2471801935 bytes) file ok but could not memory map it. This is a 
 32bit process. Please upgrade to 64bit.
```

I am on a 64-bit computer and I am getting these messages. How can I upgrade this to a 64 bit operation?

Comment: Are you using x64 version of R? try running `sessionInfo()`. On mine I see `Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`

Comment: @JonnyPhelps I'm an idiot. I accidently somehow used 32-bit. Post this as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using x64 version of R? try running `sessionInfo()`. On mine I see `Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`